# Using Regular Expression in find in Eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse

I want to find calls to a specific method with digits in a `String` argument.

Example of method call:

```
foo("123");
```

I have tried the following Regular Expression but it doesn't work:

```
foo*\d{1,}
```

I know about Ctrl-Space in Eclipse but still can't figure out how to create the search string. How shall I construct my search string to find method calls to `foo` with at least one digit in the `String` argument?

Comment: Try using `foo.*[\d]+;` or `foo.*\d{1,};`...

Comment: Thanks! foo.*\d{1,} worked!

Comment: I think `foo.*\d{1,}` will also find a line like `foo("word"); // Method 1`. You need a more specific regex, like  `foo[^(]*\("[^"]*\d+`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks but `foo.*\d{1,}` is specific enough for me.

Comment: Then a shorter variant will do, too - `foo.*\d`, but still it matches `foo123("")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that also worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `foo.*\d{1,}` (equal to `foo.*\d+` and `foo.*\d` in the end) can also match `foo1` string because it matches `foo`, then 0+ chars other than a newline as many as possible up to the last digit (`\d`).

If your method calls only have 1 argument, and you need to find a method `foo` that has a digit inside the first and only argument, it is more appropriate to use

```
foo\("[^"]*\d[^"]*"\)
```

*Details*

- `foo` - literal text `foo`
- `\(` - a literal `(`
- `"` - a literal `"`
- `[^"]*` - zero or more chars other than `"` (better `[^"\d]` though)
- `\d` - a digit
- `[^"]*` - zero or more non-`"`s
- `"` - a double quote
- `\)` - a `)`

**See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lU0fS3/2)**.

Comment: `foo\("[^"]*\d` works even if the method has more than one argument.

Comment: Yes, but it only checks if the first one has a digit. I updated to only match 1.